# How to do sql count function in laravel 5.2 for join table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

i have two table, 'devicelist' and 'devicegroup'. devicelist table contain accountID, groupID, deviceID. devicegroup table contain groupID, description.
In devicelist, groupID means group identification code and deviceID is device name(it is unique), same groupID will repeat for mutiple device .
In devicegroup groupID same as in devicelist, groupID is unique and description is group name. In my view page , need to display groupID, description from 'devicegroup' table and count of device in each groupID from the 'devicelist' table. count of device in each group need to calculate automatically instead of giving one groupID in where clause.

Can any one tell me how to write sql query, what i need to do for getting this output.
Replies are appreciable.
The query i tried is giving below.

```
    public function getIndex()
    {

$vehicleCount=DB::table('devicelist as dev_list')
    ->select(DB::raw('groupID, dev_group.description, count(*)'))
    ->join('devicegroup as dev_group', 'dev_list.groupID', '=', 'dev_group.groupID')->get();


echo $vehicleCount;


        $groups = DB::table('devicegroup')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('group.groupAdmin')->with('groups',$groups);
    }
```

updated query.

```
  public function getIndex()
    {

$vehicleCount=$vehicleCount=DB::table('devicelist as a')
    ->join('devicegroup as b', 'a.groupID', '=', 'b.groupID')
    ->select('b.groupID','b.description',DB::raw('count(a.deviceID)'))
    ->where('a.groupID','=','b.groupID')
    ->get();


//echo $vehicleCount;


        //$groups = DB::table('devicegroup')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('group.groupAdmin')->with('vehicleCount',$vehicleCount);
    }
```

and my view page is

```
   @extends('app')

@section('content')
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper">
        <div class="templatemo-content">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
                <li class="active">Group information</li>
            </ol>
            <h1>View/Edit Group information</h1>

            <p></p>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">

                        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                            <h3>Select a Group :</h3>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Group ID</th>
                                <th>Group Name</th>
                                <th>Vehicle Count</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($vehicleCount as $grp)
                            <tr>

                            <td>{{ $grp->groupID }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $grp->description }}</td>

                            <td>{{count($grp)}}</td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Action</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            {{--@if ($nam->isActive == 'Yes')--}}
                                            <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#acceptModal" data-bookingid="{{ $grp->groupID }}"><a href="{{ url('/group/edit/'.$grp->groupID) }}">View/ Edit</a>
                                            </li>
                                            {{--@endif--}}
                                            <li><a href="{{ url('/group/delete/'.$grp->groupID)}}">Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {{--//{{$groups->links()}}--}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join and where on same criteria are not doing anything. With this query you'll get devices, group them by groupID and get count by groupID.

```
$vehicleCount=DB::table('devicelist as dev_list')
    ->select('dev_list.groupID, count(*)'))
    ->join('devicegroup as dev_group', 'dev_list.groupID', '=', 'dev_group.groupID')
    ->groupBy('dev_list.groupID');
```

To answer question in comment, it is better to do do it this way, it is more readable although you go to database twice, once for other things and once for count of groupID's.

Comment: using sql i just want to take only the count of device in each groupID from devicelist table. am alresdy passing remaining groupID and description. I am adding complete code in my question. So please tell is it possible to send like that or should i send all data using same sql query.        Thanks for your valuable response :)

Comment: I've updated the answer according to your latest comment. Sorry it took me so much time.